# Fill the part of trapezoid

Tags: tikz-pgf, fill

I have a trapezoid, and i need to fill the triangle (F) inside of this trapezoid. So, is there any function, that could fill space between nodes or any other solutions? 
Thanks a lot

```
\begin {center}
\begin {tikzpicture}

\draw[step=0.5, gray!60] (0,0) grid (8,6);
\foreach \x in {0,...,6}
{
\node[text=gray!60, left] at (0,\x) {$\x$};
}
\foreach \y in {1,...,8} {
\node[text=gray!60, below] at (\y,0) {$\y$};  
}

\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt](A) at(1,1){};
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt](B) at(2,5){};
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt](C) at(6,5){};
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt](D) at(7,1){};
\node[label = $F$] at(5.5 ,3){};
\draw (A) -- (B) node[pos=.5,sloped,above] {$120 cm$};
\draw (C) -- (B) node[pos=.5,sloped,above] {$56 cm$};
\draw (C) -- (D) node[pos=.5,sloped,above] {$120 cm$};
\draw (A) -- (D) node[pos=.5,sloped,below] {$200 cm$};
\draw (B) -- (D);
\draw (A) -- (C);
\end {tikzpicture}
\end {center}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `\fill`. Or `\filldraw`, which also draws the border. You can use the `intersections` library to find the intersection between the two diagonals.

I also used `\coordinate` instead of `\node` to define `A` etc., I placed the units outside the math mode (because they shouldn't be in italic like that).

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin {center}
\begin {tikzpicture}

\draw[step=0.5, gray!60] (0,0) grid (8,6);
\foreach \x in {0,...,6}
{
\node[text=gray!60, left] at (0,\x) {$\x$};
}
\foreach \y in {1,...,8} {
\node[text=gray!60, below] at (\y,0) {$\y$};  
}

\coordinate (A) at (1,1);
\coordinate (B) at (2,5);
\coordinate (C) at (6,5);
\coordinate (D) at (7,1);

\draw (A) -- (B) node[pos=.5,sloped,above] {$120$ cm};
\draw (C) -- (B) node[pos=.5,sloped,above] {$56$ cm};
\draw (C) -- (D) node[pos=.5,sloped,above] {$120$ cm};
\draw (A) -- (D) node[pos=.5,sloped,below] {$200$ cm};
\draw [name path=a] (B) -- (D);
\draw [name path=b] (A) -- (C);

\filldraw[fill=blue!20,name intersections={of=a and b,by={M}}] (D) -- (M) -- (C) -- cycle;

\node at (barycentric cs:D=1,M=1,C=1) {$F$};
\end {tikzpicture}
\end {center}
\end{document}
```